# Convert WordPress SACK code to new admin-ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been using the [TW-SACK](https://code.google.com/p/tw-sack/) library in my plugin using the below code:

```
    <?php wp_print_scripts(array('sack')); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        where_go_count = new sack("<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/index.php");    
        where_go_count.setVar( "wherego_id", <?php echo $id ?> );
        where_go_count.setVar( "wherego_sitevar", document.referrer );
        where_go_count.method = 'GET';
        where_go_count.onError = function() { return false };
        where_go_count.runAJAX();
        where_go_count = null;
    //]]>
    </script>
```

This used to be the standard format of code on https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins, which has since changed.

I am not sure as to how I can modify the above code to use the new format with `wp_ajax_ajax`

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Note that you [shouldn't be using `wp_print_scripts()`](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/).

Comment: Agreed. But, I'd like to change the entire SACK query and not just `wp_print_scripts`